# Discord SDK: lobbyManager.ConnectLobby() returns NotFound

Tags: discord

Join lobby:

```cs
public void JoinLobby(String lobbyIdSecret)
    {
        String[] parsedItems = lobbyIdSecret.Split(':');
        lobbyId = Int64.Parse(parsedItems[0]);
        lobbySecret = parsedItems[1];

        lobbyManager.ConnectLobby(lobbyId, lobbySecret, (Discord.Result result, ref Discord.Lobby lobby) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(String.Format("Result: {0}", result));
        });
    }
```

I have created a lobby and now I'm trying to connect another user to it. However, as a result I'm getting `NotFound`. I know the ID and secret are correct. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Create lobby:

```cs
public void CreateLobby(LobbyCreatedCB cb)
    {
        // Create the transaction
        var txn = lobbyManager.GetLobbyCreateTransaction();

        // Set lobby information
        txn.SetCapacity(6);
        txn.SetType(Discord.LobbyType.Public);
        txn.SetMetadata("a", "123");

        // Create it!
        lobbyManager.CreateLobby(txn, (Discord.Result result, ref Discord.Lobby lobby) =>
        {
            lobbyId = lobby.Id;
            lobbySecret = lobby.Secret;

            Debug.Log(String.Format("lobby {0} created with secret {1}", lobbyId, lobby.Secret));
            Debug.Log(String.Format("lobby has {0} user connected", lobbyManager.MemberCount(lobbyId))); 

            // We want to update the capacity of the lobby
            // So we get a new transaction for the lobby
            var newTxn = lobbyManager.GetLobbyUpdateTransaction(lobby.Id);
            newTxn.SetCapacity(5);

            lobbyManager.UpdateLobby(lobby.Id, newTxn, (updatedResult) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(String.Format("lobby {0} updated", updatedResult));
            });

            UpdateActivity(discord, lobby);

            cb(String.Format("{0}:{1}", lobbyId, lobbySecret));
        });

    }
```

Edit: Changed join lobby snippet to be exact code that I'm using. Added create lobby function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you might've just written the parameter types backwards, but in the SDK, `id` is an `Int64` and `secret` is a `string`. If your compiler isn't yelling enough to stop before even running the code, it may be that the SDK isn't sure what to do with a string for an ID and returning `NotFound`. Could you post your snippet for creating the lobby as well?

Comment: Oh that was a mistake when I was cleaning up the snippet. Fixed it. I'll make sure to add the lobby snippet this evening. Thanks!